# Class is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm confused by this Kotlin error associated with providing an implementation for an abstract class that has been imported from a maven package.

I have a maven library that is written in Kotlin and exposes an abstract class called APIGatewayRequestHandler.  In my app that imports the library, I provide an implementation of the abstract class:

```
class GetWelcomeMessageHandler : APIGatewayRequestHandler<WelcomeMessage>()
    fun handleAPIGatewayRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): WelcomeMessage {
        return WelcomeMessage()
    }
}
```

The decompiled abstract class from the library looks like this:

```
public abstract class APIGatewayRequestHandler<T> public constructor() : com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler<com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, T> {
    public abstract fun handleAPIGatewayRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): T

    public open fun handleRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent?, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): T {
        /* compiled code */
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Class 'GetWelcomeMessageHandler' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member
public abstract fun handleAPIGatewayRequest(input: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: Context?): WelcomeMessage
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're just missing some [`override`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods) keywords. Namely, your abstract class should have it on the `handleRequest` method:

```
public abstract class APIGatewayRequestHandler<T> public constructor() : com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler<com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, T> {
    public abstract fun handleAPIGatewayRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): T

    public override fun handleRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent?, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): T {
        /* compiled code */
    }
}
```

And then your `GetWelcomeMessageHandler` should have it on its `handleAPIGatewayRequest` method:

```
class GetWelcomeMessageHandler : APIGatewayRequestHandler<WelcomeMessage>() { // <-- This curly brace was also missing
    override fun handleAPIGatewayRequest(input: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context?): WelcomeMessage {
        return WelcomeMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add "override" to GetWelcomeMessageHandler's handleAPIGatewayRequest method, I get the following error: Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'

Comment: Oh, I just realised you're also missing a `{` after the end of the `GetWelcomeMessageHandler` declaration. See the edit in my answer above.

Comment: That fixed the issue, allowed me to add override to the method.  Thanks!   The error message was very misleading

Comment: Indeed, the one about a top level function was a much better one.